# ASP.NET Core RC2 Deployment to Azure Issues - Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We've got a ASP.NET Core RC2 website on Azure and we'd like to be able to deploy it from Visual Studio Team Services (previously Visual Studio Online), but there seems to be a peculiar issue.

Firstly, I should say that the website can be deployed manually from Visual Studio and this works absolutely fine.

After finding out the hard way that they RC1 scripts don't work, I switched to the RC2 script (generated by Visual Studio) and tried but I get this error:

> Error Code: ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLEMore Information: Could not
>   connect to the remote computer ("redacted.scm.azurewebsites.net"). On
>   the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that
>   the required process ("Web Management Service") is started.  Learn
>   more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE.Error:
>   Unable to connect to the remote serverError: A connection attempt
>   failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
>   period of time, or established connection failed because connected
>   host has failed to respond redacted:8172Error count: 1.

I should've seen the port number, but I didn't so I modified the script to dump the publishProperties

```
call Publish-AspNet to perform the publish operation with publishProperties
WebPublishMethod:MSDeploy
Username:$AssessAuth
DeployIisAppPath:AssessAuth
Password:
MSDeployServiceUrl:redacted.scm.azurewebsites.net
Publishing with publish method [MSDeploy]
Executing command ["C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -source:manifest='C:\a\13c087afa\BuildAuthServer\pac\AuthServer\src\AuthServer\bin\release\netcoreapp1.0\obj\SourceManifest.xml' -dest:manifest='C:\a\13c087afa\BuildAuthServer\pac\AuthServer\src\AuthServer\bin\release\netcoreapp1.0\obj\DestManifest.xml',ComputerName='https://redacted.scm.azurewebsites.net:8172/msdeploy.axd',UserName='$AssessAuth',Password='{PASSWORD-REMOVED-FROM-LOG}',IncludeAcls='False',AuthType='Basic' -verb:sync  -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -retryAttempts:20 -disablerule:BackupRule]
```

It should hopefully be needless to say that there isn't anything listening on port 8172, at least not for my instance.

Does anybody know where the port 8172 comes from?

Is there anything I need to change on the azure app?

It seems like a bug on Publish-AspNet to me but..

Script I use for reference:

```
# Copyright (c) Microsoft Open Technologies, Inc. All rights reserved.
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0. See License.txt in the project root for license information.

[cmdletbinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
param($publishProperties=@{}, $packOutput, $pubProfilePath, $nugetUrl)

# to learn more about this file visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=524327
$publishModuleVersion = '1.1.0'

function Get-PublishModulePath{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param()
    process{
        $keysToCheck = @('hklm:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\{0}',
                         'hklm:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\{0}',
                         'hklm:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VWDExpress\{0}',
                         'hklm:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VWDExpress\{0}'
                         )
        $versions = @('14.0', '15.0')

        [string]$publishModulePath=$null
        :outer foreach($keyToCheck in $keysToCheck){
            foreach($version in $versions){
                if(Test-Path ($keyToCheck -f $version) ){
                    $vsInstallPath = (Get-itemproperty ($keyToCheck -f $version) -Name InstallDir -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | select -ExpandProperty InstallDir -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)

                    if($vsInstallPath){
                        $installedPublishModulePath = "{0}Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Publish\Scripts\{1}\" -f $vsInstallPath, $publishModuleVersion
                        if(!(Test-Path $installedPublishModulePath)){
                            $vsInstallPath = $vsInstallPath + 'VWDExpress'
                            $installedPublishModulePath = "{0}Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Publish\Scripts\{1}\" -f  $vsInstallPath, $publishModuleVersion
                        }
                        if(Test-Path $installedPublishModulePath){
                            $publishModulePath = $installedPublishModulePath
                            break outer;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $publishModulePath
    }
}

$publishModulePath = Get-PublishModulePath

Write-Host "PublishModulePath: "  $pubProfilePath

$defaultPublishSettings = New-Object psobject -Property @{
    LocalInstallDir = $publishModulePath
}

function Enable-PackageDownloader{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        $toolsDir = "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\Web Tools\Publish\package-downloader-$publishModuleVersion\",
        $pkgDownloaderDownloadUrl = 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=524325') # package-downloader.psm1
    process{
        if(get-module package-downloader){
            remove-module package-downloader | Out-Null
        }

        if(!(get-module package-downloader)){
            if(!(Test-Path $toolsDir)){ New-Item -Path $toolsDir -ItemType Directory -WhatIf:$false }

            $expectedPath = (Join-Path ($toolsDir) 'package-downloader.psm1')
            if(!(Test-Path $expectedPath)){
                'Downloading [{0}] to [{1}]' -f $pkgDownloaderDownloadUrl,$expectedPath | Write-Verbose
                (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($pkgDownloaderDownloadUrl, $expectedPath)
            }

            if(!$expectedPath){throw ('Unable to download package-downloader.psm1')}

            'importing module [{0}]' -f $expectedPath | Write-Output
            Import-Module $expectedPath -DisableNameChecking -Force
        }
    }
}

function Enable-PublishModule{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param()
    process{
        if(get-module publish-module){
            remove-module publish-module | Out-Null
        }

        if(!(get-module publish-module)){
            $localpublishmodulepath = Join-Path $defaultPublishSettings.LocalInstallDir 'publish-module.psm1'
            if(Test-Path $localpublishmodulepath){
                'importing module [publish-module="{0}"] from local install dir' -f $localpublishmodulepath | Write-Verbose
                Import-Module $localpublishmodulepath -DisableNameChecking -Force
                $true
            }
        }
    }
}

try{

Write-Host "Start Deployment for real."

    if (!(Enable-PublishModule)){
        Write-Host 'Get Publish module from nuget. NugetUrl ' + $nugetUrl 
        Enable-PackageDownloader
        Enable-NuGetModule -name 'publish-module' -version $publishModuleVersion -nugetUrl $nugetUrl
    }

    'Calling Publish-AspNet' | Write-Verbose
    Write-Host 'call Publish-AspNet to perform the publish operation with publishProperties'
    $publishProperties.GetEnumerator() | %{"{0}:{1}" -f $_.Name,$_.Value}
    Publish-AspNet -publishProperties $publishProperties -packOutput $packOutput -pubProfilePath $pubProfilePath
}
catch{
    "An error occurred during publish.`n{0}" -f $_.Exception.Message | Write-Error
    exit 1
}
```

Comment: Try adding port "443" after the deploy service url. By the way, there is a "Azure Web Deployment" task in VSTS/VSO you can use to deploy web app to Azure.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT The azure web deployment task doesn't work for me, but i guess it's probably due to the fact that the app might not be packaged properly. Not clear how to package it though using dotnet, does look like it's possible or at least documented

Comment: I must say that I had little faith that adding the port would work but it does so thanks for this

Comment: What error do you get when use Azure Web Deployment? And there is an instruction about how to deploy Asp.Net Core RC2 to Azure from VSTS in this page: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/aspnetcore-to-azure